# Всегда ли это утверждение верно?

Tags: c++

```
 assert(sizeof(int) != sizeof(long))
```

Comment: не нужно ходить в стандарты. Достаточно взять 2017-2019 студию и удостоверится, что `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) == 4`

Comment: то есть оно будет верным ?

Comment: Наоборот. Иногда нет.

Comment: а когда это будет "Наоборот" ?

Comment: Утверждение верно, если размеры типов разные. 32-битные компиляторы иногда имеют одинаковые размеры этих типов, и в этом случае утверждение **не** верно.

Comment: спасибо вам за помощь )

Comment: в студии эти типы имеют одинаковые размеры. В gcc/clang под линукс - разные.

Comment: @KoVadim, и в `msvc` и в `gcc`/`clang` на x86 их размеры одинаковые, а на amd64 — разные

Comment: я уже и не помню, когда под 32 битную пользовался.

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт языка такой радости [не гарантирует](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35844670/5533854).

Пользуйтесь стандартыми типами с фиксированной длиной - `int32_t`, например.

Answer (score 2):

Стандарт говорит только про минимальную длину типов :

```
  Type          Minimum bit width N
  signed char   8
  short int     16
  int           16
  long int      32
  long long int 64
```

А реальные размеры типов это уже на усмотрение реализации. Например, `sizeof(int)*8 == 32` вполне может быть равен `sizeof(long int)*8 == 32`.